# Finding text from the bounding box suggested by Google object detection ML

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using [Google Object Detection API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/?_ga=2.169247528.-826206404.1563811228) for our custom model.

The dataset contains business cards so all text. We have deployed our model and it is working reasonably well when we test a business card using the visual interface.

However, to use it on the backend Nodejs server we are making use of REST APIs. API request looks like below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"   https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/1023422831715/locations/us-central1/models/IOD9200669320764456960:predict   -d @request.json
```

The data returned by REST response is like below:

```
{
  "payload": [
    {
      "annotationSpecId": "5824016335306227712",
      "imageObjectDetection": {
        "boundingBox": {
          "normalizedVertices": [
            {
              "x": 0.050029,
              "y": 0.139873
            },
            {
              "x": 0.230016,
              "y": 0.251469
            }
          ]
        },
        "score": 0.998103
      },
      "displayName": "first_name"
    },
    {
      "annotationSpecId": "2224232858153648128",
      "imageObjectDetection": {
        "boundingBox": {
          "normalizedVertices": [
            {
              "x": 0.0465549,
              "y": 0.236178
            },
            {
              "x": 0.462747,
              "y": 0.30602
            }
          ]
        },
        "score": 0.98034
      },
      "displayName": "job_title"
    },
    {
      "annotationSpecId": "8910530192426926080",
      "imageObjectDetection": {
        "boundingBox": {
          "normalizedVertices": [
            {
              "x": 0.053251,
              "y": 0.410447
            },
            {
              "x": 0.452525,
              "y": 0.559461
            }
          ]
        },
        "score": 0.904657
      },
      "displayName": "address"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that this in REST case only giving the bounding boxes with the score and label. However, it is not giving the . text under that bounding box.

So, how do we get the text under the above suggested bounding boxes?

Comment: Can you post the API request too? You could also try the pretrained OCR functionality of the Cloud Vision API to check if you get better results in your use case.

Comment: i have modified the question and have added the API request

Comment: Adding the request.json would be helpful. Of course without any sensitive information if there is.

Comment: as it's a curl and our prediction engine is now down to save costs so i will try to add it later. Just curious though that why is that needed? the question is on the top of this response as how to find the text under the suggested bounding boxes.

Comment: here is the exact sample from google on request and response https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/predict